# Nightmarejs runs forever?

Tags: node.js, nightmare

I run a simple Nightmare app on CentOS 7 server (http://serverip:3000/), and it runs forever, no result returns though it passed with a simple res.send('hello world').

I'm using Node 6.11. The same code runs just fine on local PC.

```
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    //res.send('hello world'); => works fine for port 3000
      var Nightmare = require('nightmare');     
    var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: false });

    nightmare
      .goto('https://www.google.com') 
      .wait('#searchform')
      .evaluate(function () {
        return (document.body.innerHTML);
      })
      .end()
      .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('Search failed:', error);
      });
    })

    app.listen(3000, function () {
      console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
    })
```

Comment: Is google.com accessible from your CentOS server? Code looks fine to me. Either it should timeout default(30seconds) or should show some error.

Comment: There's seem problems to run  a headless nightmarejs on Linux. Lots of complaints on google but hard to get it to work.

Comment: Have you tried running it without the `Express`, i.e. directly?

Comment: Nightmare heavily relies on Electron for heavy lifting. And Electron in turn relies on several UI-focused dependencies (eg. libgtk+) which are often missing from server distros. https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/224 and https://gist.github.com/dimkir/f4afde77366ff041b66d2252b45a13db

Answer (score 3):

First off, Electron has static library dependencies you need to install separately on the server.

Additionally you need to run your node server with XVFB since it doesn't have a display.  (https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml)

The command will end up looking like this.
`$ xvfb-run node <your-server>.js`

I install everything on Ubuntu like so:

```
apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-0 libnotify-bin libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 
x11-xkb-utils xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic 
x11-apps clang libdbus-1-dev libgtk2.0-dev libnotify-dev libgnome-keyring-
dev libgconf2-dev libasound2-dev libcap-dev libcups2-dev libxtst-dev libxss1 
libnss3-dev xvfb
```

You'll need to do the CentOS equivalent.

Run electron standalone to further debug `$ <your-project-directory>/node_modules/electron/dist/electron`